# Drupal 7: Unable to update 'Available menus' in a custom content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cck

I have quite a few content types, but I need to change the available menus for a specific one.
No matter what I try, any changes to the available menus do not seem to save.

Comment: What things have you tried already? I'm guessing editing the content type and selecting the menu under 'Menu Settings' would have been the first one?

Comment: I've tried editing the content type and changing the available modules. Also I've tried disabling the location module, but no affect.

Comment: Strangely, I just tried removing 'Main menu' from available menus selected 'User menu', this saved as expected, but I can't add 'main menu' back in. It's as if it's limited to being available to only one menu.

Comment: That's very odd. I know it's tedious but would you be able to put a list of the contributed modules you've got installed in your question? One of those must be interfering with that form (perhaps `taxonomy_menu`, `workbench_access` or similar). I've got an installation with loads of contrib modules installed and the behaviour you describe isn't happening so it should be fairly easy to narrow down which one(s) are causing the problem

Comment: Oh one more thing, when you select a menu checkbox in 'Available Menus' does the select box at the bottom of that tab get filled with the hierarchy for that menu or is it empty?

Comment: The select menu populates correctly with all the hierarchies I select.
As for the modules installed I have quite a few. 
Chaos tools
Date
Field collection
Link
Menu link
Backup and migrate
Entity tokens
Flood control
Job scheduler
Libraries
Menu block
Panels breadcrumbs
Pathauto
Security Review
Site map
Token
Boost
Image Captcha
Theme Key
IMCE QYSIWYG Api bridge
Superfish
Better exposed filters
Views
Views bulk operations
Views slideshow
Views slideshow cycle
Views UI
Webform
Workbench

Comment: Aha, I think I've got it. It's the Menu link module. I'm not happy with it anyway.

Comment: I was just about to report back that exact same thing :) `menu_link` implements `hook_node_type_update()` and I think confuses the field SQL storage system with some strange code

Comment: Ok great, at least I know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion for you. 
Do you have a multi-site installation ? If you have multiple Domains, check under

- Site-Information. (Normally there should be a message box with an info like "You may submit changes to the current domain at admin/structure/domain/view/3/config.")
- Click admin/structure/domain/view/3/config
- enable the menus for the appropriate content type in the Tabs at the end of the page

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: Change machine name of this Content Type to something different. This will probably involve updating some views etc. where you use this content type.
Ideally you'll need to find what is causing the lock of available menus so check all modules you've installed